# How to update data for each row using function and data from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a problem with updating data for each row in the `acrticles_pl_vector` table using function in set clause and data take from another table.

For example I have a pseudocode:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateTsvector () 
RETURNS status AS
$$
BEGIN
    FOR EACH ROW otherTable
     UPDATE acrticles_pl_vector
     set vector = to_tsvector('polish', otherTable.title || otherTable.content);
     WHERE id = otherTable.id

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateTsvector () RETURNS void AS $$
  UPDATE acrticles_pl_vector
    SET locale = 'pl', vector = to_tsvector('polish', ot.title || ot.content
    FROM otherTable ot
    WHERE id = ot.id;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```